# What is the name of the other vertex of an undirected edge?

Tags: graphs, terminology

Let's say I have an **undirected** graph with an edge $e = \{a,b\}$ connecting vertices $a$ and $b$.

Taking vertex $a$, what is the name of the other vertex? Is it the "co-vertex"? Or simply the "other vertex"? Or the "neighbouring vertex"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no set phrase; any clear description will do. "The other vertex in $e$", "the other endpoint of $e$", "$b$".

I've never heard of "co-vertex" and "neighbouring vertex" is vague, since $a$ might have multiple neighbours.

Comment: There is such phrase : the vertex adjacent to $a$

Comment: No, since there may be many vertices adjacent to $a$.

Comment: The OP looks for the name similar to coVertex or neighboring vertex. We call those adjacent vertices. Depending on your sentence you can add as many details as you need like "the vertex $b$ adjacent to vertex $a$ in $e$".  It hugely depends on the sentence, however it still has a name.

Answer (score 0):

In graph theory, b would then be called an **adjacent vertex**.

Adjacent vertices are defined as follows.
Two vertices m and n are adjacent, if they are the end vertices of the same edge e.

Comment: It is _an_ adjacent vertex but the question is asking specifically for the other end of a specific edge.